# How to scroll the UserControl when the focus is in a Devexpress TextEdit which has masking

Tags: c#, scroll, devexpress, textedit

I am developing a Windows application where I am loading a Devexpress XtraUserControl which has TextEdits with masking (Regex like "[0-9]{0,7}" to make my textedit accept only numbers) and with out masking on to my Windows Form.

The Problem here is my UserControl size is larger than my Form size which enables me toScroll.Scroll works fine when the focus is in TextEdit with out masking but the scroll does not work when the focus is in TextEdit with masking.So how can i get my scroll work independent of the TextEdits.

Thanks,

Chaithu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you contacted DevExpress support? It appears that the TextEdit scroll event is handled differently based on the Mask Type selected. You will need to create a custom TextEdit.

[Reference](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q247969.aspx)